# Flexpaper inside iframe size issue

Tags: html, css, flexpaper

I am facing a problem and any kind of response would be respectful.

I want to show people's cv's ( pdf type ) on my page and I am using flexpaper to do so.
I have some iframes with some specific style ( width,height ) and inside those iframes I place my document.

My problem is that he document's size is much bigger than the iframe's, which forces it to create scroll bars.

I want to make my document preview appear smaller in order to fit the iframe size without any scroll bars appearing. Below is an image of my preview so far.

[image: image1]

```
<div class="some class that i get from my php">
                            <i class="icon-download-alt"></i>
                            <a href="a link that i get from my php">
                                Cover Letter</a>   <a onclick="$(this).parent().find('iframe').toggle();return false;">(Preview)</a><br><br>
                            <iframe src="/flexpaper/php/split_document2.php?subfolder=&doc=documentsName" style="width:100%; min-height:400px; display:none;"></iframe>
                            <br>
                        </div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Post your code please.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the FitWidthOnLoad parameter to true in the viewer like so:

FitWidthOnLoad : true

- make sure you have 100%/100% on width/height on the viewer and you should be sweet